# Advice in Time simulation

Tags: omnet++

I just created VANET simulation with AODV protocol .. Then running it  using omnet++ and sumo ..please your advice for :-

```
1- Which button it better to use ( run button , or fast button ) 

2- When I using the run button, my simulation take along time upto 12 hour with sample number of car .. So if the number of car increase  it will take more long time, So how can increase the speed of simulation to get less run time ..
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For running simulations (for collecting results and after verifying that your model works as intended) I recommend two things:

- Run your simulation in release mode. This means compiling the code with the flag `MODE=release`. More details can be found in the [OMNeT++ user manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:build-sim-progs:debug-and-release-builds).
- Run your simulations on the command line - do not use any OMNeT++ GUI. If you want to collect results this is by far the fastest way as you do not care about the GUI. How to use the command line is explained in the [dedicated OMNeT++ user manual section](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:run-sim:cmdenv).

Comment: Thanks for your advice but please my omnet++ is 4.6 this will work and what is the coal from using this mode ... For second point can u advice me how can using the CLI or run it from the cli so i can get the result .. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the user manuel for details. It will also work with OMNeT++ 4.6.
For more details how to run a simulation on the command line visit [the OMNeT++ user manual page about Cmdenv](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:run-sim:cmdenv).